Looking for a "Kidnapping" movie?
I don't remember much but what I remember is, a girl wants to travel to somewhere and wants money from her father. 
I think her father blames her for doing drugs and he refuses to give money. 
So she storms out of the room and from that moment, no one sees her. Her father thinks she went to her friends and he doesn't care about her but then he can't find her anywhere. Also her father is a business man and he is well known person.His friend is helping him to find his daughter, his friend finds her but she is already dead.When he learns this, he wents into depression and his wife leaves him.The kidnappers are his bodyguard and his secretary.When he learns that, he and his friend goes to her place and tries to talk with her but she's getting scared, she hides her daughter and runs off the roof. Her foot slips and she clings to corner of the roof.They were about the leave her but as soon as he saw her daughter (the secretary's daughter) who cries, he tells his friend to save her.He saves her and the father and his friend leaves her place. The father goes to that place, where is his daughter wants to go and the movie ends.
Note: I saw this movie this year, I think the movie was from 2010's and I think they were speaking korean but I am not sure because I watched on TV and it was translated to my language. I think the place that the girl wanted to go was a lake shows sky or it was connected to sky somewhat. The cast were all asian, thats all I can remember.
